# Two similar data sets to be displayed on the same pivot chart

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have two data sets.

```
Week  IN   US   FR   UK   MX
1     200  550  0    1    0
2     70   257  309  33   0
3     49   306  293  49   8
4     77   308  408  53   65
5     117  341  343  59   81
```

.....

```
Week IN   US   FR   UK   MX
1    0    0    0    0    0
2    36   129  194  24   0
3    51   322  287  57   0
4    75   292  373  50   56
5    80   249  296  56   76
```

....

Against each week,

I have number of orders requested in the first table

I have number of orders delivered in the second table.

I want a pivot chart which shows the same

Comment: Looks like your data is already in "pivoted" form. What would be the expected output of the pivot table / chart?

Comment: Is this a real question?? Add another Column with ordered and delivered as the value and create 1 pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2010 or newer you could use [PowerQuery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379), a free add-in provided by Microsoft, to unpivot and combine your two datasets. I believe in Excel 2016 PowerQuery is already included as *Get & Transform*.

Create a new query with PowerQuery and open the *Advanced Editor*. Remove any text already appearing in the editor and use the below code to get an unpivoted and combined table.

```
let
    Requested = Table.AddColumn(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Requested"]}[Content], {"Week"}, "Country", "Value"), "Type", each "Requested"),
    Delivered = Table.AddColumn(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Delivered"]}[Content], {"Week"}, "Country", "Value"), "Type", each "Delivered"),
    Combined = Table.Combine({Requested, Delivered})
in
    Combined
```

The first two lines after `let` are getting the data from your tables (assuming your two datasets are in tables named *Requested* and *Delivered*), using `Table.UnpivotOtherColumns` to unpivot them and then adding a column `Type` to indicate if the line is for a request or a delivery.

`Table.Combine` simply appends one table to the other (putting all the lines from the deliveries below the requests).

Close the Advanced Editor and click *Close & Load* in the query editor to add the query results to an Excel sheet. Using the resulting table you can easily create a pivot table that shows the combined data.

Since the query is still connected to the source tables, anytime your data changes / gets updated you can refresh the query (similar to a pivot table) to get the new data.